# Custom attributes in Tomcat's server.xml

Tags: tomcat, server.xml

I have a Java web application running in Tomcat 7.0.5x.  I need to deliver this application to our customer who has multiple disparate networks on which the application/tomcat will run.

One of my requirements is to allow the end user to configure the Tomcat server's Connector port from a small thick-client utility.  This utility will store the configured port by opening the server.xml, updating the port attribute and saving the result.

The problem is that there are multiple Connectors that need to be defined so some additional logic needs to be implemented to ensure the correct Connector is updated.

One of the ideas that has been thrown around is setting a custom attribute on the Connector that would uniquely identify that Connector as being the one that needed to be updated, e.g.,

```
<Connector foo="bar" port="8080" ...
```

Then, we'd just perform an XPath search for a Connector element with a foo="bar" element.

Having the custom attribute doesn't seem to break Tomcat, so my question is:  Is there anything wrong with this?  Is there anything particularly "bad" or "smelly"?

The other alternative is to pass around a `newPort` and an `oldPort` then perform an XPath search like:

```
XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("//Connector[@port=\"" + oldPort + "\"]")
```

and then set `newPort` as the new value.

This doesn't seem like such a bad idea, but there are other attributes that are configurable so the parameter list for this update method could get cumbersome.  Anyway, the design discussion is not the appropriate place for Stack Overflow, but I'd like to know if there is anything definitely wrong with using a custom attribute in server.xml.

Thanks for listening...